# Intercept GET request and redirect to generated file

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension and using chrome.webRequest to intercept all GET requests. One of the request gets an XML file from http://test.com/bla.xml. This XML file is hosted on my webserver, so getting it is straight forward. The question I have is, how can I send a generated XML file and return it. I know how to intercept and modify the URL in the webRequest, but I'm not quite sure how to send it to a file I create on the fly.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        if (details.url === 'http://test.com/bla.xml') {
            var xmlDoc = "<person>me</person>";
            return { redirectUrl: xmlDoc }; 
        }
```

**I want to be able to redirect the XHR to a dynamically generated file. This file isn't necessarily an XML document, it could be a jpg file that I create with a stored blob.**

Update: I have tried to forward to a data URI and now get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/bla.xml. The request was redirected to a URL ('data:text/xml;base64,sdfkldsfjdslfjsfsjf') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.
```

I have added http://*/, and data:* to the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to dynamically generate the file you want to return on your server.

Barring that, have you tried a data: URI? Given that you can control the redirect URL, you can encode the content you want to return in a data: URI and return that as the redirect target. See below for reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Comment: I tried using data URI but i get XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/bla.xml. The request was redirected to a URL ('data:text/xml;base64,sdfkldsfjdslfjsfsjf') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.

Comment: It looks like you asked this separately and it was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171162/chrome-webrequest-cross-origin-disallowed-scheme-on-redirect-to-data , but for posterity, this is going to be allowed in Chrome 37 (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308768).