# chrome.webRequest cross-origin disallowed scheme on redirect to data:

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome.webRequest api to intercept xhr's and redirect to a saved blob i have in chrome.storage.local and get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/bla.xml. The request was redirected
to a URL ('data:text/xml;base64,sdfkldsfjdslfjsfsjf') which has a disallowed 
scheme for cross-origin requests.
```

the chrome.webRequest api states that "Redirections to non-HTTP schemes such as data: are allowed."

I've tried adding data:* or *:* to the permissions in the manifest with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting to `data:`-URIs is fully supported by the webRequest API (and you don't need the non-existent `data:*` permission for it).

Your requests failed because data:-URI access through XMLHttpRequest was not supported until Chrome 39. (Starting in Chrome 39, you will be able to fetch `data:`-URIs using XMLHttpRequest, see http://crbug.com/308768 for more info).

Comment: thanks for the reply! would you happen to have any input on how I could accomplish this then ?