# cross origin on base64 image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to display an image that is base64 encoded (the html is an AngularJS directive template):

```
<div id="iframe" ng-hide="loading"></div>
<img ng-show="loading" id="tweetLoader" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAPYAAP///wAAAP...AAAAAA==" >
<div class="error" ng-show="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

I removed part of the base64 code since it's very long, if it's absolutely needed, I'll add it.
Chrome (in firefox this doesn't happen) shows me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAPYAAP///wAAAP...AAAAAA==.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Also, this error isn't showed every time.. It seems pretty random.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.21

Is it a chrome bug or something?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding Base64 Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: I disagree.. I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm trying to understand why this is happening, since base64 images are working on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't flag as duplicate cause it's not the same question but I think the answer could help you
[chrome.webRequest cross-origin disallowed scheme on redirect to data:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171162/chrome-webrequest-cross-origin-disallowed-scheme-on-redirect-to-data):

> Your requests failed because data:-URI access through XMLHttpRequest was not supported until Chrome 39. (Starting in Chrome 39, you will be able to fetch data:-URIs using XMLHttpRequest, see http://crbug.com/308768 for more info).

Comment: But i'm not trying to fetch the image using `XMLHttpRequest`, I put the base64 in the src attribute of the img tag.   Maybe angularJS does it by itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in chrome security restrictions that prevent it from loading images from a url so just add this property and it will be working fine

```
img.crossOrigin = " ";
```

It will be fine for chrome alse

Comment: `crossOrigin` only works if the server replies with CORS headers. In the case of `data:`-URIs, there is no server.